# Alert user if number is multiple of 30

Tags: javascript

I have in my database a row with a specific value. There is a system that inscrements that value automatically, the value is not constant.

And I need to build a script that alerts the user everytime this value it's multiple of 30.

Demonstration:

- When value is 30 -> Alert
- When value is 45 -> Do not alert
- When value is 60 -> Alert

Everytime a user receives an alert, I record the event in a database, to have an history of data.

This script will be running inside a Node JS server, that will run at least once a day.

My code:

```
function validateValue(id, interval) {
    //Callback that returns me the present value
    retreiveValue(id, function(value) {
        //Checks if the value is multiple of 30
        if (value % interval == 0 ) {
            //Retreive the lastest alert to check if the event was already sent
            retreiveLastValue(id, function(configs) {
            if (value == configs.value && interval == configs.interval) {
                console.log("already sent");
            }else{
                console.log("send alert");
            }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

But in this case, the script will only send the alerts if the the value is 30, or 60. And since the server will run once a day, I would like to find a way to check if the number passed the barrier again.

Demonstration:

- When value is 29 -> Do not Alert
- **Server down during the transition from 29 to 30**
- When value is 31 -> Do not alert

How can I build a script that prevents this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm... Not sure what you want exactly... What should happen is the server is down during that transition?

Comment: Does the value start at 0 for every user session? You can keep a counter of alerts already sent. Then check `if( Math.floor( value / interval ) > alertsCount ){ sendAlert(); alertsCount += 1 }`

Comment: Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/84n8wd4b/ the `value` increments by a random value in range 1...3 to simulate interrupted connection or whatever reason there may be for the value to skip an exact multiple. The idea is to send the alert as soon as the multiple of `interval` is crossed.

Comment: Jordamus When the server is down, the value increments automatically. And I would like to find a method that checks if the value already reached a number that its multiple of 30, when I turn the server on.

Comment: Yes Pawel, that's exacly what I need, please answer the question so I can validat your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of checking if the `value` is an exact multiple of `interval`, i.e. modulo `value % interval` is `0`, you can use division `Math.floor( value / interval ) = n` to check if the value is at least `n * interval`. This `n` is also the number of alerts that need to be sent, so keep track of the alerts and issue a new one as soon as `n` is larger than the number of alerts sent (i.e. another multiple has been crossed).

```
var alertCount = 0;
function validateValue(id, interval) {
    //Callback that returns me the present value
    retreiveValue(id, function(value) {
            if( Math.floor( value / interval) > alertCount ){
              sendAlert( value );
              alertCount += 1;
            }
    });
}
```

[Demo on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/84n8wd4b/)